# Unable to uninstall the Nucleon EDR Agent

Tags: self, malware, antivirus, epp, nucleon

I have installed Nucleon EDR to protect my endpoint. After completing my testing, I want to temporarily uninstall the EDR Nucleon Agent. However, I am unable to do so, and I also cannot access the Registry configuration.

How can I uninstall the agent? Is there a way to access the registry?

Here is the error that occurs when attempting to uninstall the agent:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S8w3.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nucleon EDR solution offer a self protection for its agent to not be destroyed by malware, to uninstall you must disable the agent from the administration console.

Check the documentation:

nucleonsecurity.freshdesk.com/a/solutions/articles/151000038478